# Quando Seleciono Uma CheckBox Todas São Selecionadas (Apenas A Escolhida Deve Ser Marcada)

Tags: angular

Quando seleciono uma CheckBox todas são selecionadas, preciso que apenas a Checkbox escolhida seja selecionada.

Podem me ajudar? Obrigado!

**tabela.component.html:**

```
    <table class="table">
    
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Titulo</th>
        <th scope="col">Descricao</th>
        <th scope="col">Valor</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let livro of livros">
        <th scope="row">
          <div class="form-control">
            <input  type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isActive" name="id" value="{{livro.id}}">
            {{livro.id}}
          </div>
        </th>
        <td>{{livro.titulo}}</td>
        <td>{{livro.descricao}}</td>
        <td>{{livro.preco}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**tabela.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LivrosModel } from '../../models/livros-model/livros-model';
//Imports de Services
import { LivrosService } from '../../services/livros.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabela',
  templateUrl: './tabela.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabela.component.css']
})
export class TabelaComponent implements OnInit {


  livro: LivrosModel = new LivrosModel();
  livros: Array<any> = new Array();
  @Input() isActive: any | undefined;

  constructor(private livrosService: LivrosService) { 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.listarLivros();
  }

  // Método para Listar os Produtos:
  listarLivros(){
    this.livrosService.livrosList()
    .subscribe(resposta => {
      this.livros = resposta;
      console.log('Lista de Livros:', this.livros);
    },
    () => { 
      console.log('Falha ao Listar Livros');
    }
    );
  }
// Método para excluir os Produtos:
  removerLivros(){
    console.log('Item Marcado:', this.isActive);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, descobri o motivo.

Basicamente quando estou atribuindo o `[(ngModel)]` para todos os CheckBoxs que forem criados dentro da minha tabela, e quando mudo o valor do `isActive` eu acabo mudando para todos.

A Solução encontrada foi usar FormGroup e usar o formControlName para recuperar o valor das minhas CheckBox.

Então o que eu fiz foi:

Criar um FormGroup

```
formulario!: FormGroup;
```

Fazer a construção dele dentro do meu ngOnInit

```
this.formulario = this.formBuilder.group({
  check: [null]
});
```

Atribuir o meu FormGroup ao formulário:

```
<form [formGroup]="formulario">
```

Passar o FormControlName  dentro do meu Input da Checkbox

```
<td><input type="checkbox" formControlName="check"></td>
```

Com isso eu consigo obter o valor True e False da CheckBox sem marcar todas as caixas.